# (PHP/MySQL) Problems with turning a database result into an array

Tags: php

**BACKGROUND**: I have a database that looks like this.

```
TITLE                        ANDROID       OS X        WINDOWS
World of Goo                    1            1            1
Superman 64 GOTY Edition        0            1            1
Seinfeld: The Game              1            0            1
```

And so on, intended to represent a game collection. There's one varchar column representing the title, and then booleans for each platform.

My desire is to use PHP to turn that database into a page that reads

```
 Super Mario 64 (N64)  
 World of Goo (Windows, Android)
```

And so on, just listing off which platforms a title is available for.

**PROBLEM**: Depending on which solution I use, I either wind up with (Windows) (Android) or (Windows,Android)(Windows,Android)(Windows,Android)(Windows,Android).

Here's what's written.

```
$q = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM GAMES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$platforms = array();                   
    foreach ($row AS $column => $value) {

        if ($column == "Name") {
            echo "<br />" . $value;
            continue;
        }


        if ($value == 1) {          
            array_push($platforms,$column); 

        }

        if (count($platforms)) {
            print_r($platforms);
        }
    }
}
```

The intent of this code is

1. Loop over every item in a row.
2. If the cell you're on is the name, echo it.
3. If the cell you're on has a "1" in it, then we own the game for that platform, so store the name of that platform in an array.
4. At the end of the row, show me that array.

Now here's the problem: if I execute that code, the array is fully-formed, but I don't get one array back, I get one array *per column in my database*, so it just echoes the platforms back over and over.

If I move line #3 ("$platforms = array();") into the foreach loop, then that problem is avoided, *but* I don't get one fully-formed array, I get a separate array for each individual platform.

So... where *should* I be putting that line? I'm messing something simple up with the way I manage that platforms array, but I'm not clever or experienced enough to figure it out. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Platforms should be a multi dimensional array. In the `while($row=mysql_` call you will add `$platforms[$name] = array`, then in the `foreach` loop you will add the platforms; `array_push($platforms[$name],$column);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve your issue.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $platforms = array();
    echo $row['TITLE'];
    foreach($row as $column => $val):
        $val == 1 ? $platforms[] = $column:;
    endforeach;
    echo '<pre>', print_r($platforms, true) ,'</pre>';

}
```